# Wiring up a dolls house with LEDs and a 9V battery

Tags: led, resistors, wiring

I'm trying to wire up a dolls house that I've built for my daughter with 7x 3mm white LEDs (https://www.jaycar.co.nz/white-3mm-led-4300mcd-round-clear/p/ZD0142)

I'm powering it with a 9V battery and have already blown 2 LEDs, so I guess I need to add resistors.

The guide I was following (http://judyry.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/where-to-begin_17.html), didn't mention them at all, so that's on me for not researching properly first.

Regardless, I'd greatly appreciate some guidance on what size and how many resistors I'll be needing.

If my Ohm's Law calculations are correct then the resistance is 290Ω, but does that mean I divide that across the 7 LEDs and get 7x ~41Ω resistors or do I need 7x 290Ω resistors?

Comment: RElated : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340373/leds-in-parallel-each-with-its-own-resistor

Comment: Your battery will last twice as long if you put two LEDs in series with one resistor. The second LED basically lights for free.

Comment: That's an awfully bright LED to illuminate a single room of a dollhouse.

Comment: You're going to blow LEDs until you realise how they work.  - they run at a specific voltage ranges - too high or the wrong direction and they blow, and there's actually a mention of what size resistors to use on the jaycar website you linked. You want s 300 ohm resistor

Comment: As you plan this out, draw your intended circuit on paper first, and calculate the voltage across each LED to make sure it's in the correct range.  It may actually be possible to do this without adding resistors to the circuit, which would be the most efficient type of circuit.

Comment: How about you don't use 9V, but a 1.5V cell together with a [Joule Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief)? They are quite easy to build, and you can happily power an LED, even with a battery which you would normally consider empty.

Comment: Will it power seven LEDs though? Or will it need seven batteries and seven lots of circuitry?

Comment: If OP is confused about the resistor for a LED, asking him to research how a joule thief works is counterproductive at best.

Comment: He doesn't need to research how it works to make one. I've done it, it is easy to build. I have run two or three LEDs in parallel on one Joule Thief, seven is a bit much perhaps, but if you build one, you can also build three. And you won't blow your LED because the voltage cannot be too high.

Comment: By the way, $4.90 for a single white LED is way overpriced. If you have some time (about a month of delivery time) you can get 100pcs of white LEDs on Ebay for ~$1.50. Just look for chinese vendors on Ebay.

Comment: Heck, you could buy 100 leds from a local eBay seller for 5 to 10 dollars shipped

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, they do skip the resistors, but that's because they bought LEDs with the resistors already attached and under heat shrink. Hobbyist markets like Doll Houses or Trains often sell the LEDs with the resistors, at a premium.

That little bulge is the resistor:
[image]

Your Ohm's law calculation is correct.
(9V Source Voltage - 3.2 LED Forward Voltage) / 0.020 Amps = 290 Ohms.

But your application is a bit off. 7 parallel leds with a 41 ohm resistor each at 20mA, would only drop 0.82 volts, which means the current increases and the leds blow. But 7 parallel leds with a 290 ohm resistor each would work. Inefficiently.

**You're wasting 116 mW of power out of 180 mW per led/resistor pair. 2/3rds of your battery power is being wasted in the resistor as heat.**

The 3 solutions are decrease the current, or put 2 leds in series with a resistor, or 3 in series without a resistor.

3 in series without a resistor only works with a 9V battery, as the 9V battery has a high Equivalent Series Resistance (basically a resistor), and the forward voltage of the 3 leds add up to over 9V. The brightness will be slightly lower.

2 in series with a smaller resistor would allow you to use the full 20mA current without issue. (9v - 3.2v - 3.2v) / 0.020 = 130ohms. The leds share the current, and only 1/4th of power is wasted in the resistor, leading to double the battery life.

Lowering the current would result in a longer life, just change the amount of current in ohms law from 0.020 (20mA) to 0.010 (10mA). These leds will still be illuminated fairly well at 10 mA.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately most of that went over my head. How would your solutions look visually? Like I said, complete novice.

Comment: Try http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz :)

Comment: Legend, I get what you mean now and that makes a lot of sense. It may require me to undo some wiring though =(. Thanks again!

Comment: 3 LEDs without a resistor does not sound like a great idea. (It shan't blow the LEDs, but you'll very likely get noticeable discrepancy in luminosity between different triples.

Comment: @yo as they are wired in different rooms, that's not likely to matter. L

Comment: I ended up wiring 2 LEDs in series with a 150ohms resistor (x3) and wiring the single remaining one with a 330ohms resistor. Works really well now - thanks everyone for the help. And I only blew 3 LEDs learning...:)

Comment: @DavidMay Sweet :) Picture? Also, definitely find a better source for your leds. 5 bucks a pop is not worth it.

Comment: [Wiring](https://i.imgur.com/ou8T1mo.jpg), [House](https://imgur.com/296DQFL), [Lit up](https://imgur.com/QAlIuRr). Switch and wiring still need tidying up, painting and covering up with "ivy" to hide them a bit. Wife still working on the on the other curtains and I still need to find "lampshades" or "globes" to defuse the lights a bit. Otherwise 90% done. ;)

Comment: You can use semi opaque hot melt, or you can sand the leds a bit.

Answer (score 10):

You need resistors, as Finbarr says  you can use 2 LEDs per resistor.

Visually, I think you should just go ahead and try it. I would try a lot higher resistor value and see if it is bright enough, maybe 1K per LED pair for about 3mA.

Use lower value (or two or three resistors in parallel) to get more brightness. Use two resistors in series to make them dimmer.

Modern decently made LEDs are very bright with a few mA. Take mcd ratings with a grain of salt- sometimes the "maximum" is quoted (they guarantee that the LED will be dimmer than specified). Anyway if true, it's a fairly decent-to-middling LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL5ZHk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you have an odd number of LEDs you may have trouble getting (and keeping as the battery discharges) the odd man out to be the same brightness. Better to have a dummy LED that is not visible.